# Can ask why empty one keep random into none?

Tags: system-verilog

I craft a randomize parameter, and i try to run 15 times.
However the empty one keep give me none option. 
I think better come here ask , i stuck almost half day.

I add the whole of the randomize for the request.
This randomize work correct except the empty keep giving me none option. 
I want it work like full, can success run a randomize number in None, single and dual mode.

```
   typedef enum {STANDARD, FWFT} mode_type;
   typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} output_status;
   typedef enum {NONE, STATIC_SINGLE, STATIC_DUAL} prog;

   rand mode_type MODE;
   rand output_status OUTPUT_REG;
   rand prog PROGRAMMABLE_FULL;
   rand prog PROGRAMMABLE_EMPTY;
   rand int COMMON_CLK;
   rand int DEPTH;
   rand int DATA_WIDTH;
   rand int PROG_FULL_ASSERT;
   rand int PROG_FULL_NEGATE;
   rand int PROG_EMPTY_ASSERT;
   rand int PROG_EMPTY_NEGATE;


   constraint set {
      COMMON_CLK inside {0, 1};
      DEPTH inside {16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072};
      DATA_WIDTH inside {[1:1024]};
     }
constraint FULL_ASSERT {
     solve DEPTH before PROG_FULL_ASSERT;
     if (PROGRAMMABLE_FULL == STATIC_SINGLE){
      PROG_FULL_ASSERT inside {(0.50 * DEPTH), (0.75 * DEPTH), (0.9 * DEPTH)};
   } else if (PROGRAMMABLE_FULL == STATIC_DUAL){
      PROG_FULL_ASSERT inside {(0.50 * DEPTH), (0.75 * DEPTH), (0.9 * DEPTH)};
   } else {
      PROG_FULL_ASSERT ==  0;  
   }
               }
   constraint FULL_NEGATE {
     solve PROG_FULL_ASSERT before PROG_FULL_NEGATE;
     PROG_FULL_NEGATE < PROG_FULL_ASSERT;
     if (PROGRAMMABLE_FULL == STATIC_DUAL){
      PROG_FULL_NEGATE inside {(0.50 * DEPTH), (0.75 * DEPTH), (0.90 * DEPTH)};
   } else {
      PROG_FULL_NEGATE ==  0;  
   }
               }

   constraint EMPTY_ASSERT {
      solve DEPTH before PROG_EMPTY_ASSERT;
      if (PROGRAMMABLE_EMPTY == STATIC_SINGLE){
      PROG_EMPTY_ASSERT inside {(0.10 * (DEPTH-1)), (0.25 * (DEPTH-1)), (0.50 * (DEPTH-1))};
    } else if (PROGRAMMABLE_EMPTY == STATIC_DUAL){
      PROG_EMPTY_ASSERT inside {(0.10 * (DEPTH-1)), (0.25 * (DEPTH-1)), (0.50 * (DEPTH-1))};
    } else {
      PROG_EMPTY_ASSERT ==  0; 
    }
                }

   constraint EMPTY_NEGATE {
      solve PROG_EMPTY_ASSERT before PROG_EMPTY_NEGATE;
      PROG_EMPTY_NEGATE >= PROG_EMPTY_ASSERT;
      if (PROGRAMMABLE_EMPTY == STATIC_DUAL){
      PROG_EMPTY_NEGATE inside {(0.10 * (DEPTH-1)), (0.25 * (DEPTH-1)), (0.50 * (DEPTH-1))};
   } else {
      PROG_EMPTY_NEGATE ==  0;
   }
                }
```

Result:

```
`define COMMON_CLK             1

    `define DEPTH             16

    `define DATA_WIDTH           298

    `define MODE     STANDARD

    `define OUTPUT_REG   TRUE

    `define PROGRAMMABLE_FULL    STATIC_DUAL

    `define PROG_FULL_ASSERT              12

    `define PROG_FULL_NEGATE               8

    `define PROGRAMMABLE_EMPTY   NONE

    `define PROG_EMPTY_ASSERT              0

    `define PROG_EMPTY_NEGATE              0
```

Full one work nice, but empty keep give me none option. I think this is no way run 15times, everytime will keep none.

Comment: You cannot use real numbers in a constraint. Please show us the declarations for _every_ variable used in your constraint expressions. What is "the empty one"? You have no variable by that name, and more than one containing empty as part of its name.